# HAProxy rewrite HTTP requests based on HTTP method

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

I have REST API.

For the sake of simplicity lets say I have two services:

- read.request.com
- write.request.com

How I can rewrite all **read** requests (GET method) to **read.request.com** and all **write** requests (POST, PUT, DELETE methods) to **write.request.com** with HAProxy?

Comment: On the backend are the two services two separate programs that run on separate ports/ip address or are both services handled by the same program?

Comment: This is the same code, but uses different databases, one for write and one for read. I know that this can be solved on application level, but I want to solve this using load balancer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not quite sure which of these is applicable for your situation but hopefully one is.

**One Backend**

I think this is your situation.

```
frontend http-in
    bind *:80

    acl is_post method POST
    acl is_get  method GET

    http-request set-header Host write.request.com if is_post
    http-request set-header Host read.request.com if is_get

    default_backend api

backend api
    server one localhost:8080 check
```

All this does is check which method is being used and sets the `Host` header accordingly before passing the request on to `localhost:8080`.

**Two Backends**

In this set up you have have one instance of the code running for just read requests and another instance just for write requests. In this case the read code is running on `localhost:8080` and the write code is running on `localhost:8081`.

```
frontend http-in
    bind *:80

    acl is_post method POST
    acl is_get  method GET

    use_backend write if is_post
    use_backend read  if is_get

backend write
    http-request set-header Host write.request.com   #optional
    server write_one localhost:8081 check

backend read
    http-request set-header Host read.request.com    #optional
    server read_one localhost:8080 check
```

This option starts the same as the previous one by checking which method is being used but instead of using one HAProxy backend it splits out into two. The `http-request` line inside each backend is optional for this configuration.

Hope that helps.